# TCPDF Set Font via CSS font-family

Tags: html, css, fonts, tcpdf, font-family

I'm using the latest version of TCPDF, and found that I cannot set fonts with CSS`font-family` when using the `writeHtml` method. The *only* way that the font is set is if I use `SetFont`, but that won't work out nicely for me as the document needs to have multiple fonts and the template is created using one HTML view file.

Here's that template file so far:

```
<style media="all">
    html, body, p, h1, h2, h3, td, span {
        font-family: 'HeavyDisplay' !important;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
</style>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:27pt;color:#2998ff">Tax Receipt</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Company Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:7pt;letter-spacing:.8pt;color:#999">&nbsp;<br>Please retain for income tax purposes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can confirm that the `font-size` property works.

Additionally, I have tried inlining the `font-family` property for each tag, but that doesn't make a difference.

Is this a bug with TCPDF?

Comment: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_033.phps, what the problem you are getting in `SetFont` method?

Comment: No problem with `SetFont`. I cannot set the font with CSS, which is what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use library TCPDF or others using `<style>` tag or `css` file

```
<style media="all">
    html, body, p, h1, h2, h3, td, span {
        font-family: 'HeavyDisplay' !important;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
</style>
```

better you use style attribute instead `<style>` tag or `css` file

```
<body style="font-family: 'HeavyDisplay' !important;font-size: 10pt;"></body>
```